# How can I use react-native-image-marker with Expo to add watermarks to images?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I am attempting to add watermarks to images within an Expo project using the `react-native-image-marker` library. My goal is to overlay text and potentially images onto existing images displayed within the app.

I have imported the `react-native-image-marker` library into my Expo project and attempted to use the `Marker.markText()` function to add watermarks to images.

However, I am encountering issues when invoking this function, specifically receiving a `"TypeError: i is not a function"` error message.

Comment: Please share some code